# backintime can't backup files from Firefox profile because they are created by root

Tags: firefox, backup

After a recent update of Mozilla Firefox, I have three files in my firefox profile folder:

```
.rw------- 29k root   root   22 Sep 13:06 cert9.db
.rw------- 29k root   root   22 Sep 13:06 key4.db
.rw------- 457 root   root   22 Sep 13:06 pkcs11.txt
```

This Firefox profile folder is included in my `backintime` backup, but as the files are created by root, `backintime` can't read them.

What would be the best way to come around this?